# UTF8MB4 character encoding for Spring MVC and Thymeleaf application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, utf8mb4

I was able to store utf8mb4 character in my MySQL database following instructions in this post by Mathias Bynens.

```
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
```

I can see the utf8mb4 characters (eg:♥) being returned from the database to my Controller in debug mode in Netbeans.

My web.xml configuration. **NOTE**: Setting the configuration to UTF-8 works fine but not UTF8MB4. I've also tried lowercase utf8mb4

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8MB4</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thymeleaf configuration

```
 <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF8MB4" /> 
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="additionalDialects"> 
        <set> 
            <bean class="com.cmr.dialect.BLCDialect"/> 
        </set> 
    </property> 
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF8MB4" /> 
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

This is my hibernate connection url which I assume is working fine because I can see proper characters being returned testing in Netbeans debug mode.

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/site?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

This runtime error occurs when I have the UTF8MB4 configuration in web.xml

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF8MB4
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.getCharset(B2CConverter.java:71)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setCharacterEncoding(Request.java:1561)
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setCharacterEncoding(RequestFacade.java:307)
javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setCharacterEncoding(ServletRequestWrapper.java:113)
javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setCharacterEncoding(ServletRequestWrapper.java:113)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Removing web.xml UTF8MB4 config throws this runtime error in

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF8MB4
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:42)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:83)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.WriteConvertor.<init>(C2BConverter.java:174)
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.C2BConverter.<init>(C2BConverter.java:47)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.setConverter(OutputBuffer.java:531)
org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.checkConverter(OutputBuffer.java:497)
org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:631)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.getWriter(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:109)
org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:221)
org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:146)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Edit:
Here are mysql variables

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Googling got me no results. Seems like this question is number 1 on google if you search for the exception.

Comment: I had a similar issue with this encoding, but  I use hibernate. Parameters that works for me of are : <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property> and of course utf8mb4 encoding on mysql side...

Answer (score 2):

Answered in this forum by Zemi.

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF8MB4-character-encoding-not-working-td4026185.html#a4026187

utf8mb4 is just MySQL setting so I had to use UTF-8 in my application settings.

And I also needed URIEncoding="UTF-8" in my server.xml file.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8983" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```